# Comparison between dates

Tags: python, date, statistics

I have CSV file of over 1,400 dates in date format (DateList).
I want to see how closely any given date (GivenDate) matches to these 1,400 dates.

**Example 1:**
If all dates in DateList are 1 January 2000, and the GivenDate is 1 January 2000, Python would output 1.

**Example 2:**
If half the dates in DateList are 1 January 2000, and half the dates in DateList are 2 January 2000, and the GivenDate is 1 January 2000, Python would output 0.5.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would recommend you to go step by step, first ingore the CSV stuff and focus on converting string date representation into something, what you can compare, e.g. datetime.datetime (see Python doc). Then, convert the difference to values you wish to have. And finally proceed to CSV file. In any case, trying some related tutorials would help you starting.

Comment: Hold on... I think you mean one of the following: Example 1 should output either 0, or example 2 should output 0.5 correct? Or example 1 outputs 1 and example 2 outputs 1.5. Can you refine your expectations please?

Comment: Example 1 would output 1 because there is a complete match between the DateList and the GivenDate. Example 2 would output 0.5 because there is a 50% match between the DateList and the GivenDate.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a difference between the two dates, figure out how many days of difference that is - and then tally the sum. Something like this perhaps?

```
from datetime import date

def get_date_delta(DateList, GivenDate):
    # assume DateList contains an array of date objects
    # assume GivenDate contains the day we are matching (also date object)

    dateDeltaSum = 0
    for d in DateList:
        dateDeltaSum += Math.abs((d-GivenDate).days)

    dateDeltaSum = dateDeltaSum / len(DateList)

    return dateDeltaSum
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
def define_match(date_list, given_date):
    count = 0
    for x in date_list:
        count += 1 if x == given_date else 0
    return count / len(date_list)
```

test:

```
>>> from datetime import date

>>> date_list = list(date(2000, 1, 1) for x in range(1400))
>>> given_date = date(2000, 1, 1)
>>> define_match(date_list, givenDate)
1.0

>>> date_list = list(date(2000, 1, 1) for x in range(700))
>>> date_list.extend(list(date(2000, 1, 2) for x in range(700)))
>>> define_match(date_list, givenDate)
0.5
```